# Laravel 5.0.* middleware to remove prefix locale from url before routes are processed

Tags: laravel, routes, middleware

I am looking for a way to make all app route's have multiple locales without using route groups. This is because I use an external extensions package, which means routes are registered in many places.

Essentially I want to have /foo/bar as well as /en/foo/bar, /de/foor/bar, /es/foo/bar etc all to be recognised and processed by the /foot/bar route

```
 Route::get('foo/bar', function () {
     return App::getLocale() . ' result';
 });
```

So the above would give me 'en result' or 'de result' or 'es result'.

I already have middleware that sets the locale based on the path segment. I have tried the following with no luck.

```
   ...
   $newPath =  str_replace($locale,'',$request->path());

   $request->server->set('REQUEST_URI',$new_path);

 }

 return $next($request);
```

Hopefully this is possible, or there is some other way of achieving it.

**EDIT------**

Based on a comment below I quickly hacked it by adding the following code into public/index.php. Hopefully this will give a better idea of what i'm trying to achieve by editing the request object.

```
$application_url_segments = explode( '/', trim( $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"], '/' ) );

$application_locale = $application_url_segments[0];

$application_locales = ['en' => 'English', 'de' => 'German'];

if ( array_key_exists( $application_locale, $application_locales ) ) {

    $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"] = str_replace( '/' . $application_locale,'',$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"] );

}
```

Comment: I couldnt personally find anything to easilly do what you are after. I may have missed something though but I looked through both laravel's and symfonys Request class. Unfortunately I didnt find anything of value. That being said, you can intercept the request in the index.php file in the public folder and then set `$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]` before it creates the request object and it will work.

Comment: I have quickly tried something within the index.php file which means I can edit the server variable before it gets to Laravel. However I think ill need something better, as I use configs for locales etc.

Comment: I'm facing the same problem and I can't get it work either.  It seems the `Request` object is immutable.  I have set a quick hack in index.php as well, but I also use the URI for locales etc, so still researching.

Answer (score 3):

Here is the correct code to edit the URL before the routes get called.

```
<?php namespace App\Providers;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Application;
use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Request;

class LanguageServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider {
    public function register() {
      Request::instance()->server->set('REQUEST_URI',"/uri/");
    }
}
```

To note, fetching the path from the Request instance without duplicating it first will for some reason cause the REQUEST_URI to not be editable. I assume somewhere in the codebase laravel is initializing the request when you call the path() method.

Comment: Is there a way to do this in Lumen?

Comment: Tom C, I've tried this in Laravel 5.8.36 and while the REQUEST_URI is changed in the server vars the Router is not picking up on the changed routes. Any ideas??

Answer (score 1):

You can easily achieve this by hooking into the app a bit earlier. Create a ServiceProvider and create a `register` method and put your logic in there.

```
<?php namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProviders;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Request;

class LocaleServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider {

    // Fires during the registration of this ServiceProvider :)
    public function register(Request $request) {

        // Altar the Request object here
        // ...
        // ...

    }
}
```

Comment: This didn't work. I got an error because of the following error

LocaleServiceProvider::register(Illuminate\Http\Request $request) must be compatible with Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider::register()

I have used the contructor to pass in an app instance and used $app->request. However - I am still unable to get it to actually change anything. The route is still handled the same

Comment: I have made an edit to the original question/detail above if that helps

Answer (score 0):

none of this actually worked for me with 5.5. The approach is good, but for me the request-argument did not get injected into the `register` method, likewise `instance()` is not a static method and should not be called as such.

However, using the service container to aquire an instance of `Request` made it possible to change the request-path before it is parsed inside the ServiceProviders `register` method:

```
public function register()
{
  $this->app->make('Illuminate\Http\Request')->instance()->server->set('REQUEST_URI',"/what/ever/");
}
```

I hope this helps somebody!

Cheers

edit: Pastor's answer is technically more correct as he uses the Facade instead of the actual Class. However, the injection of neither works on `register` but you can alternatively use:

```
use \Illuminate\Support\Facades\Request
//...
public function register()
{
  Request::instance()->server->set('REQUEST_URI',"/what/ever/");
}
```