# Remove segment or change REQUEST_URI in Laravel Request?

Tags: laravel

Does anyone know of a way to remove a segment from the current Request in Laravel?

For example, I want to remove segment one so...

```
/one/two/three
```

becomes...

```
/two/three
```

I am getting the first segment using:

```
$segment = Request::segment(1);
```

This answer by Tom C works to replace the server setting but it doesn't seem to be applied to routes.
[Laravel 5.0.* middleware to remove prefix locale from url before routes are processed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34865784/laravel-5-0-middleware-to-remove-prefix-locale-from-url-before-routes-are-proc)

```
Request::instance()->server->set('REQUEST_URI',"/two/three/four");
```

Thanks

Comment: The correct way is to redirect to the desired path

Comment: @amd  I don't really want to send a redirect header to the client and repeat the request all over again. It's a performance hit if happening on every request.

Comment: Then you should reconsider what you are trying to do, why you have such need?

Comment: @amd Needed for API Versioning - the code by Tom C actually did work but within the public index.php file. Got it working with full Semantic Versioning in the URL or Accept Header so all good. :)

Comment: Hah thanks @regan The funniest thing is that I just got back into Laravel development, needed to do this and had completely forgot about the old question and seemingly saw a link to my own answer :|

Answer (score 1):

Found a better (the correct) way to do this... much nicer.

If you want to access and modify the $request variable before it hits your controllers... for example I use it to process an API request based on semantic versioning...

Create the middleware file you want run, ie:

```
App/Http/Middleware/SemanticVersioning.php 

<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;
use Closure;

class SemanticVersioning
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        $semver = [];
        $request->merge(['semver' => $semver]);
        return $next($request);
    }
}
?>
```

Then add the class to the protected $middleware array in:

```
App/Http/Kernel.php

protected $middleware = [
    \App\Http\Middleware\SemanticVersioning::class,
];
```

You're able to access all $_SERVER vars etc inside that class and can modify the $request variable to add whatever you want.

The additions or mods you make to $request will now be available in your controllers.

Answer (score 0):

The answer by Tom C lead me to the /public/index.php page where the REQUEST_URI can be modified without any problems.

[Laravel 5.0.* middleware to remove prefix locale from url before routes are processed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34865784/laravel-5-0-middleware-to-remove-prefix-locale-from-url-before-routes-are-proc)

Just look for this piece of code and do whatever you want/need to do with any $_SERVER vars BEFORE it.

```
$response = $kernel->handle(
    $request = Illuminate\Http\Request::capture()
);
```

If you want/need to work on the $request variable comment out the code above and change to this:

```
$request = Illuminate\Http\Request::capture();// REQUIRED
$request->merge(['somekey' => $somevalue]);// DO WHATEVER YOU WANT HERE
$response = $kernel->handle($request);// REQUIRED
```

Any changes you make to the REQUEST_URI will flow through the app. If you add variables to the $request they will also be available anywhere you reference them.

Yay.

Comment: In your example, could `'somekey'` be `'REDIRECT_URI'`? That didn't work for me. Setting `$_SERVER['REDIRECT_URI']` directly did work though.

Comment: Oops, I wrote `REDIRECT_URI` in my previous comment, but meant `REQUEST_URI`.

Comment: @TylerCollier - sorry I took so long to reply! I just added another answer to this post with a much easier solution - I think it's actually the correct way it should have been done. Works a treat and is much more elegant. Hope it helps! :)

Comment: All good. I don't recall exactly what I was doing at the time, but I remember that my solution was to just switch from Apache to Nginx to resolve my proxying issues. Unfortunately this means I can't verify you newer solution/answer, but thanks for posting it and hopefully it helps others (or me in the future)!